Why are Stripe Checkout sample amounts hardcoded? (How do we get basket specific unit price, quantity and currency?)
I don't understand the Stripe express checkout sample code: https://docs.stripe.com/elements/express-checkout-element/accept-a-payment.
Amounts and currency are hardcoded. What if someone buys more than one product - or is paying in another currency?
Client-side
expressCheckoutElement.on('confirm', async (event) => {
  const {error: submitError} = await elements.submit();
  if (submitError) {
    handleError(submitError);
    return;
  }

  // Create the PaymentIntent and obtain clientSecret
  const res = await fetch('/create-intent', {
    method: 'POST',
  });
  const {client_secret: clientSecret} = await res.json();

  const {error} = await stripe.confirmPayment({
    // `elements` instance used to create the Express Checkout Element
    elements,
    // `clientSecret` from the created PaymentIntent
    clientSecret,
    confirmParams: {
      return_url: 'https://example.com/order/123/complete',
    },
  });

  if (error) {
    // This point is only reached if there's an immediate error when
    // confirming the payment. Show the error to your customer (for example, payment details incomplete)
    handleError(error);
  } else {
    // The payment UI automatically closes with a success animation.
    // Your customer is redirected to your `return_url`.
  }
});

Server-side
const stripe = require("stripe")("my precious");
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static("."));

app.post('/create-intent', async (req, res) => {
  const intent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: 1099,
    currency: 'usd',
    // In the latest version of the API, specifying the `automatic_payment_methods` parameter is optional because Stripe enables its functionality by default.
    automatic_payment_methods: {enabled: true},
  });
  res.json({client_secret: intent.client_secret});
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Running on port 3000');
});

Please help a newb.
I've seen some suggestion of passing this information in the body of the post request:
client-side
  const res = await fetch('/create-intent', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
         amount: myamount,
         currency: mycurrency
    )}
  });

server-side:
  const intent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: req.body.amount,
    currency: req.body.currency,
    // In the latest version of the API, specifying the `automatic_payment_methods` parameter is optional because Stripe enables its functionality by default.
    automatic_payment_methods: {enabled: true},
  });

But it's unclear how:

expressCheckoutElement.on('confirm', async (event) => {}) gets these variables - are they just globals set outside its scope? (eg those with which we mounted the express checkout element)
the server-side code validates the client-side order details if we're just passing the former to the latter

please - help a newb.

You can consider using a web session to score the charge amount, and ensure the amount that you set on frontend options is consistent with the backend PaymentIntent. Otherwise your customer will likely file a dispute if they paid a different amount than what they saw on the Google Pay/Apple Pay PaymentSheet.
